# Implicit termination of start conditions in flex without using `unput()`

Tags: lex

Let's say I'm parsing hexadecimal numbers in flex. I have something like this:

```
%x hexnumber
%%
"0x"                { BEGIN hexnumber }
<hexnumber>[0-9A-F] { process_digit(); }
```

This works fine; the `0x` prefix starts hex-parsing mode, and then each digit is processed in turn.

The problem is that a hex constant doesn't have an explicit terminator token. So, how do I switch back to the INITIAL state? By the time I know that the next character isn't part of the numeric constant, it's been consumed.

I can always push it back onto the input stream with `unput()`:

```
<hexnumber>.        { unput(*yytext); BEGIN INITIAL; }
```

...but I'd very much prefer not do this (because of implementation details beyond the scope of this question using `unput()` is very expensive for me).

I know that the generated state machine is capable of automatically switching back to the INITIAL state without consuming the next character, because otherwise rules like `[0-9A-F]+` wouldn't work. Is there a way to achieve this using explicit start conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `yyless(0)` instead of `unput(*yytext)`; `yyless` is essentially free since it only adjusts a couple of pointers. It makesno attempt to reallocate or move the input buffer. (You also need `BEGIN(INITIAL)`, of course.)

A much messier solution would be to use trailing context to distinguish between hex characters followed by other hex characters:

```
 [[:xdigit:]]/[[:xdigit:]]    process_digit();
 [[:xdigit:]]                 process_digit(); BEGIN(INITIAL);
```

But that is a lot less flexible.